How to Control StringContainsQ
I have the following code
edges = {N5001 -> N1003, N50012 -> N1099, N5003 -> N48059, 
   N50035 -> N22007, N2345 -> N5003};
edges2 = ToString /@ edges;
edges3 = 
  ToExpression@
   Select[edges2, StringContainsQ[#, {"N5001", "N5003"}] &];
{VertexCount[edges3], EdgeCount[edges3]}
EdgeList[edges3] // TableForm

The output I'm looking for is only the following
N5001->N1003
N5003->N48059
N2345->N5003

I want the code to exclude nodes with any digits that follow the "1" in N5001 and nodes with any digits that follow the "3" in N5003. Hence, N50012 is excluded and N50035 is excluded.
How can I modify or restrict StringContainsQ to look for edges that contain N5001 (not N50012) and N5003 (not N50035).

You should probably rewrite the question so that it is understood that you care about the length of the node name rather than what characters it contains. It's currently very confusing to have StringContainsQ in the title when you don't actually care what the strings contain.

Assuming that you want Rules where the first argument has a string length of 5 characters. This can be achieved by
Select[edges3, StringLength[ToString[#[[1]]]] == 5 &] 

{N5001 -> N1003, N5003 -> N48059, N2345 -> N5003}


Select[edges, StringFreeQ[ToString[#],
       "N500" ~~ ("1" | "3") ~~ DigitCharacter ..] &]

(*    {N5001 -> N1003, N5003 -> N48059, N2345 -> N5003}    *)


(+1) - You could use StringFreeQ instead of Not[StringContainsQ ...

Roman: Thank u but what I'm really looking for (and I've not stated it best) is ANY number of digits after the 5th position should be excluded, where N is the first position. I just want to keep the first 5 positions only; that is, Nxxxx and not Nxxxxyzw, etc.

Thanks @eldo – updated!

@user42700 I've updated the pattern: notice the .. repeated pattern.

I have nodes like these "N5001", "N5003", "N5005", "N5007", "N5009", "N5011", "N5013","N5015", "N5017", "N5019", "N5021", "N5023", "N5025", "N5027" and I want the code to stop at the 5th position for any of these nodes where N is in position 1

Do you mean something like excluding the pattern "N50" ~~ ("01" | "03" | "05" | "07" | "09" | "11" | "13" | "15" | "17" | "19" | "21" | "23" | "25" | "27") ~~ DigitCharacter .. or am I still not getting it?

Just to exclude any nodes that have more than 5 digits -- so, a node N51032 would be excluded; a node N513923 would be excluded. Just keep the first 5 positions in the string only, where N is in position 1

Select[edges3, LessEqualThan[5]@*StringLength@*SymbolName@*First]


Look for only N5 cases. Suppose I have edges = {N500122 -> N5003, N50012 -> N1099, N5003 -> N48059, N5003 -> N22007, N234544 -> N5001, N3010->N2111}. Then I'm looking for this result: N500122 -> N5003, N5003 -> N48059, N5003 -> N22007, N234544 -> N5001

Can you please update your question with your actual requirements? People won't necessarily see that you've used comments to change your actual requirements.
